# Reflector for isomorphisms

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category of algebraic structures, for example just sets, consider the morphism category $\mathrm{Isom}(C)$ and its full subcategory consisting of isomorphisms. I think that it is reflective. But how can we write down the reflector explicitly? Note that $\mathrm{Mono}(C)$ is clearly reflective, the reflector maps $f : A \to B$ to $A/\ker(f) \to B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a reflective subcategory. The reflector replaces the domain (considered as a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$) of an object in $[\mathbb{2}, \mathcal{C}]$ with its codomain. Indeed, if $g$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{C}$, then
$$[\mathbb{2}, \mathcal{C}] (f, g) \cong \mathcal{C} (\operatorname{codom} f, \operatorname{codom} g) \cong [\mathbb{2}, \mathcal{C}](\mathrm{id}_{\operatorname{codom} f}, g)$$
so we have the required left adjoint.

Another way of seeing this is to observe that the full subcategory of $[\mathbb{2}, \mathcal{C}]$ spanned by the isomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent (as a subcategory) to the image of the fully faithful functor $\Delta : \mathcal{C} \to [\mathbb{2}, \mathcal{C}]$, and $\Delta$ has a left adjoint (as well as a right adjoint).

Comment: Ah, yes, it's so simple. Thanks.